# How to start a new main class with new console window

Tags: java, console, program-entry-point

I'm creating a client-server chat application in Java. I'm decided not to use GUI like java swing. I'm only using java console window. Right now, I want to open a new main class with a new console tab. I have no idea how to do this.

**Calling new main in Main.java**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("This is main console.");
    ServerMain.main(null);
}
```

**ServerMain.java**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("THIS IS SERVER MAIN.");
}
```

**Output**

```
This is main console.
THIS IS SERVER MAIN.
```

Both output remains in the same console window.
What I want is separate that two output string into two separated console tab window.

Comment: I believe this would depend on the platform, as console application (provided by OS) might behave differently.

Comment: The only real way to interact with the window manager is through the GUI toolkits.

Answer (score 0):

When you run a non-GUI Java program, it does not have any idea of its surroundings.  It only expects a stream of input bytes available to you as System.in, and two streams of output bytes sent "elsewhere" available to you as System.out and System.err.

That's it.  Nothing else.

What you want to do is to instruct the CMD.EXE window to *do* things.  This is firmly in the "elsewhere" part of the description above, and is very common in the Unix world where many different character based terminals have been used long before graphic screens were available.  The typical trick is to send so-called Escape codes in your output stream sent to the terminal which was then interpreted differently than just to show characters.  Typically this could be moving the cursor, cleaning the screen and switch character sets and much more.

Your problem is now that CMD.EXE does not understand very many Escape codes and you can therefore not tell it to do what you want as-is.

Either get a better terminal emulator to run your Java code inside or write some scaffolding outside your Java program grabbing the two streams and sending them to the appropriate terminal tab.